# Erro ao exibir alertas com $_SESSION[""]

Tags: php, session

Estou realizando um site teste para treinar um pouco de `php`, estou utilizando `$_SESSION[""]` para mostrar alertas, porém, ao subir para um `servidor` que não seja local, os alertas param de funcionar.

LINK do projeto-> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8AhqmUgCKAfTWlSdW5TMkFzVmM/view?usp=sharing

*Arquivo do banco para importar dentro da pasta phpi

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>PHP I</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/padroes.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <a class="title" href="index.php">NarglothStore</a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="adiciona-produto.php"><li>Adicionar Produtos</li></a>
                <a href="estoque.php"><li>Estoque</li></a>
                <a href="login.php"><li>LogIn</li></a>
                <a href="logout.php"><li>LogOut</li></a>
                <a href="contato.php"><li>Contato</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

logicaUsuario.php

```
function verificaUsuario(){
    if (!usuarioEstaLogado()){
        $_SESSION["error"] = "Você não tem acesso a essa funcionalidade";
        header("Location:index.php");
        die();
    };
};
```

adiciona-produto.php

```
<?php 
require_once("header.php");
require_once("banco-categorias.php");
$categorias = listaCategorias($conexao);
$produto = array("nome" => "", "preco" => "", "descricao" => "", "categoria" => "1");
$usado = "";
require_once("logicaUsuario.php");
verificaUsuario();
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php 
    require_once("conexao.php");
    require_once("header.php");
    require_once("logicaUsuario.php");
    require_once("logica-alert.php");
    mostraAlerta("success");
    mostraAlerta("danger");
    mostraAlerta("error");
?>
```

logica-alert.php:

```
<?php
    function mostraAlerta($tipo){
        if (isset($_SESSION[$tipo])){
?>
            <div class="alert-box">
                <p class="alert <?= $tipo ?>"><?= $_SESSION[$tipo] ?></p>
            </div>
<?php
            unset($_SESSION[$tipo]);
        };
    };
?>
```

Logs de erro:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/comunica/public_html/testes/murilo/phpI/header.php:26) in /home/comunica/public_html/testes/murilo/phpI/logicaUsuario.php on line 9

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/comunica/public_html/testes/murilo/phpI/header.php:26) in /home/comunica/public_html/testes/murilo/phpI/logicaUsuario.php on line 2
```

Comment: Precisa descobrir se acontece algum erro, no primeiro script adicione essas duas linhas: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Precisa ver qual é a saída de texto que o `header.php` faz.

Comment: @rray, como faço para verificar e corrigir ?

Comment: O segundo erro significa que uma saída de texto (html, BOM, echo, warning ou mensagem de erro) saiu quando o cabeçalho já foi enviado. Precisa se tem algum desses antes de uma chamada do `header()`

Comment: Não estou conseguindo :/

Comment: Coloca o conteúdo de header.php

Comment: No index.php deixa o include/require do `header.php` antes do `conexão.php`

Comment: não funcionou, tentei também trocar os require_once por include em todas as páginas, mas não funcionou

Comment: Acho que o jeito é ir testando o index com um include/require assim vc isola o problema de maneira mais fácil

Comment: @rray, eu fiz isso, porém, em todos os casos deu o mesmo problema... vou zipar o projeto e colocar o link aqui, teria como você testar ele ai ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP"](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php)

Lembre que header() deve ser chamado antes de qualquer saída ser enviada, seja por tag HTML normais *(no nosso caso o html do header.php), linhas em branco no arquivo ou do PHP.

O arquivo logicaUsuario.php e qualquer outro arquivo que possa vir a usar o camando `header()` deve vir antes de qualquer saida de dados na tela seja tag html ou texto, normal ou linhas em branco.

Comment: Uma dica, sempre pesquise se no site já não existe resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=session_start%20send%20session%20cache%20limiter%20headers%20already%20sent

Comment: Eu fiz a pergunta porque não achei uma igual no site, mas obrigado mesmo assim @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: não funcionou, fiz de tudo com o header(), mas não funcionou

Comment: coloca o header.php como ultimo arquivo a ser inserido