# Erro de redirecionamento 'header()'

Tags: php, header

```
<?php
require_once("banco-produtos.php");
require_once("logicaUsuario.php");
verificaUsuario();
require_once("header.php");

$id = $_POST['id'];

removeProduto($conexao, $id);
$_SESSION["success"] = "Produto removido com sucesso";
header("Location:estoque.php");
die();
```

logicaUsuario.php

```
function verificaUsuario(){
    if (!usuarioEstaLogado()){
        $_SESSION["error"] = "Você não tem acesso a essa funcionalidade";
        header("Location:index.php");
        die();
    };
};
```

banco-produtos.php

```
require_once("conexao.php");
function removeProduto($conexao, $id){
    $query = "delete from produtos where id = {$id}";
    return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
};
```

Error_log

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/comunica/public_html/testes/murilo/phpI/header.php:23) in /home/comunica/public_html/testes/murilo/phpI/remove-produto.php on line 11
```

Segui as dicas dadas em outras duas perguntas, uma minha e outra que havia sido marcada como duplicata da anterior, porém nenhuma delas resolveu o meu problema, já modifiquei o código tantas vezes quanto possível, tentei colocar o `header()` e/ou a verificação de usuário.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, leia a descrição da pergunta, eu já tentei usar o que haviam colocado nessa outra pergunta ai, porém não funcionou, ele continua gerando esse erro...

Comment: Já li a descrição da pergunta e cheguei a conclusão de que é duplicada. Todas as possíveis causas para o problema estão relatados nessa pergunta na referência de duplicação. Caso esteja passando por outro problema, precisa entrar em mais detalhes.

Comment: Eu sei que estão relatados, segui o que estava lá e mesmo assim continuou o mesmo erro

Comment: Murilo, mas sinceramente, você viu quantas respostas tem na outra pergunta? Tem que certeza que tentou tudo e não funcionou? A solução para o problema é aquela, não tem outra explicação. Inclusive, se for o caso, a sua pergunta seria fechada da mesma forma, caso você não saiba relatar com detalhes o problema ocorrido (poderíamos fechar como "esse problema não pode ser reproduzido").

Comment: Talvez você esteja com outro problema que não está descrito na pergunta, como outro arquivo com um código em branco no início. Um bom teste a ser feito é dar um `CTRL+U` na página do erro e ver se não tem nada sendo enviado para o browser antes (isso é falado em uma das respostas linkadas)

Comment: tentei cara, eu to desde as 10:40 da manhã tentando resolver esse problema, tiveram alguns outros menores que resolvi, porém só falta esse mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou tentar explicar o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/comunica/public_html/testes/murilo/phpI/header.php:23) in /home/comunica/public_html/testes/murilo/phpI/remove-produto.php on line 11
```

Diz: "Você não pode modificar os headers após já ter enviado um outputbuffer (saída)".

[Pelo tópico postado anteriormente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169927/erro-ao-exibir-alertas-com-session), no arquivo **header.php** existem buffers de saída (código HTML), resultando nesse warning.

Toda modificação de Header deve ser feita antes de qualquer saída, seja o **include()**, **require()** ou até mesmo um **echo** com o **outputbuffer** ligado.

Comment: Não fui eu que dei o negativo, mas praticamente foi o que já foi respondido na outra pergunta. Essa pergunta já foi indicada como duplicada.